# search for value in a array and check if value is valid

Tags: c#

I am making a blackjack and have made a card class. My card class works but I need to have the Value set accessor search the values array and determine if the value argument is valid or not. I am not sure on how to do this. 
Any help would be appropriated

Here is what I have for my card class

```
private class Card
{
    public enum SUIT
    {
        HEARTS,
        SPADES,
        DIAMONDS,
        CLUBS
    };

    private SUIT _suit;
    private String _value;

    public Card(SUIT suit, String value)
    {
        _suit = suit;
        _value = value;
    }

    private String[] values =
    {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

    public SUIT Suit
    {
        get { return _suit; }
        set { _suit = value; }
    }

    public String Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: check out the linq [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

Comment: So when someone calls `Card.Value = "some value";` you want to verify that "some value" is contained in the `Card.values` array?

Comment: can you explain further what your problem with checking a valid value is, because the whole thing seems kind of trivial. Is it that you do not know how to handle receiving an invalid value?

Comment: Why don't you make value an integer between 1 and 13?   Override ToString to change 1 to 'A', 11 to 'J', 12 to 'Q' and 13 to 'K'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the provided value is allowed, you can use the `Contains()` method on an `IEnumerable`

I'd also recommend a better variable name than `values`. How about `validValues`?

```
private String[] validValues =
    {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
public String Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set 
    { 
        if (validValues.Contains(value))
            _value = value; 
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException(); //or whatever you like
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use an `enum` for the value as well:

```
public enum Value
{
    Two,
    Three ,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace,
};

public Value Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

As a design note, since the value of a card instance should not change, a better design would be to only set the suit and value in the constructor and make the properties read-only.  It would also be a good use of the Factory Pattern, but that may be more advanced than you want right now (if you don't understand what it is, don't use it).

Comment: Also, you might want to make `Ace = 1`, so it at least has one of it's valid values!

Comment: @RufusL It will have a value of 11 (one more than the previous value of 10)

Comment: This solution has some serious drawbacks: That code would make it impossible to differentiate between a jack, a queen and a king. Value.Jack, Value.Queen and Value.King are aliases for the same enum value. Also bad, the setter would accept the value `0`, since zero is always a valid enum value. The enum itself is a good idea, but I would advice against encoding the card values within it. Just encode the values somewhere separate, like in a `Dictionary<Value,int>`

Comment: @HugoRune Excellent point about the face cards being indistinguishable.  I'll remove that part.  Not sure I fully agree with the `0` argument.  Yes it's _possible_ but one would have to _intentionally_ use 0, and the value of doing so is not evident.